# do native English speakers completely omit the /r/ sound in /ˈev·riˌwʌn/ (everyone)?

Tags: pronunciation

Most Asian non-native English speaker pronounce the `/r/` clearly in the word everyone `/ˈev·riˌwʌn/`.

However, when hearing the pronunciation of `/ˈev·riˌwʌn/` in some online English dictionary, I hear no articulation of `/r/` sound at all.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/everyone

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/everyone

So the native English speaker seems to say `/ˈeviˌwʌn/`.

so , **do native English speakers completely omit the /r/ sound in /ˈev·riˌwʌn/ (everyone)?**

Comment: No, not no**r**mally. Not at all, eve**r**. Unless there is a p**r**oblem with a lisp.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the dictionary where you heard this? And can you tell us what your native language is?--knowing your phonology may help us understand what you are missing.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: I'm Vietnamese native speaker

Comment: You've cited the pronunciation as eviˌwʌn but the Oxford link gives it as 'ɛvrɪwʌn; note the R just after the V. Also, I can hear it when I hit the speaker icon next to the word. Admittedly the R isn't exceedingly clear (and that may be down to the compressed audio quality) but it's definitely there. In the Cambridge link (which seems to have less compressed audio) it's very clear indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Just... no. The only people I've heard omitting the r sound in everyone either have a speech impediment, or are affecting one. I can't even think of a regional accent where that would be the case, though perhaps the deep southern USA may, ***possibly***, pronounce it less clearly than other parts of the English speaking world. (It may sometimes sound like "eveh-won", although even then most southern speakers I've heard would be closer to "everh-won".)

I don't know which dictionary this is, but either you've misinterpreted it, or I think you need a different dictionary.

Comment: It's hard to Imagine even someone from Mississippi doing that. Then again, I could be wrong: I can never understand them anyway. :)

Comment: @ tchrist: That shouldn't have made me laugh... but it did anyway. (No disrespect to anyone from the fine state of Mississippi, of course!)

Comment: @tchrist It's more closer to "evreh-won" and maybe reduced down to a sort of "evr(eh?)uhn" (question mark being glottal stop) in the South.  We do pronounce it, but the reduction of the latter half of "every" and how we can say "one" (destressed and monophthongized), the R might be hard to hear for people not used to the accent.

Answer (score 3):

Here in Texas, I think "everyone" is pronounced "ya'll"... :)

Seriously though, the 'r' should be there if you listen for it.

Answer (score 0):

In all my native English life I have never heard the r in every to be silent. Your online dictionary may be confusing every with ever. Ever is often pronounced with no r: evah/eveh or similar sound.